# How to add a property according to context to models of a QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models

How do you guys are adding extra-fields to your models according to some business rules just before hitting the template without polluting the models?

Lets say I have a `QuerySet` containing models of type `Member`.

After retrieving those models, I want to add a property `online` dynamically to it (which is not in the database).

I want to be able to set this property according to values retrieved from a cache server like:

```
members_online = get_online_members_ids()
for m in members.all():
    m.online = m.id in members_online
```

This snippet doesn't work because 1) `.all()` returns a copy of the `QuerySet`, 2) the property `online` doesn't exist in my model.

After that in my template I want to be able to print the `online` property.

My first steps in Django, please shed a light on my problem, thank you !

**EDIT:**

My problem is a little bit more complex... My list of members is actually a relation of another model:

```
categories = Category.objects.select_related('members').all()
for cat in categories:
    for m in cat.members.all()
        m.online = m.id in members_online
```

And categories is what is being sent to my template/piston handler.

Answer (score 1):

Reason 2 is irrelevant: Django models, like all Python objects, can have any attribute applied to them at any point.

To get around reason 1, you just have to convert to a list:

```
all_members = members.objects.all()
for m in all_members:
    m.online = m.id in members_online
```

and now pass `all_members` to the template.

The other way of doing this would be to pass `members_online` separately to the template, and check the status separately there:

```
{% for m in members %}
    {% if m.id in members_online %}online{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

although that would be less efficient if you need to use the online status of each member several times (although even then, you can use `with` to save the current status to a temporary variable).

Comment: I'll edit my question, because technically your solution is correct to my question. But I didn't portrayed the whole picture.

Comment: My second solution would still work with your edited description, surely.

Comment: I don't want to do that, I'm also exporting to JSON

Answer (score 1):

I never used this method before, but thinking about it now I came up with something like this:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    # your fields

    @property
    def online(self):
        # load the list if it wasn't loaded before and save it as a class attribute.
        # that way `get_online_members_ids()` will be called the first time this
        # property is accessed, and that one time only.
        if not hasattr(Member, 'members_online'):
            Member.members_online = get_online_members_ids()
        return self.pk in Member.members_online  # return online status for the particular member
```

You would then use this in your template like it was an ordinary field:

```
{% for member in members %}
    {{ member.online }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:** thinking about this more I think you need to be careful, because there is a possibility that once loaded the static attribute will stick around longer then you expect, and be reused in subsequent requests. Haven't tested this myself.

Comment: About your update: yes. I think we should do directly `return self.pk in get_online_members_ids()`. And do caching in `get_online_members_ids()`